# How do I enable global menu for Qt applications?

Tags: unity, appmenu, qt

Is there a way to enable the global menu for Qt applications on Unity? By default they do not use it.

Comment: Do you have `appmenu-qt` installed ?

Comment: Yes, but it makes no difference.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 I reproduced it as an answer, should I keep the comment or delete it?

Comment: @MarceloHashimoto You can delete the original comment now. It helps keep things nice and tidy that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Qt3 or Qt4? Qt3 is not supported at all and there is no way to work around that. But Qt4 is supposed to be supported out of the box, and if it doesn't for you it might be a bug.

Comment: global menu in Qt4 applications installed via software center seems works fine, but others not, e.g.: in official distribution of [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/downloads#qt-creator) it doesn't work. I'm wondering what could be an issue and how to address it?